# Scale/normalize 3D data points along one axis?

Tags: python, normalization

For a research project, I am asked to classify different types of spine curvatures using 3D landmarks of vertebrae.

[3D Plots of 2 patients' spine landmarks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSgKx.png)

[What I want the plots to look like more or less](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWU2J.png)

Since I am aiming to focus only on curvature, I need to scale/normalize the 3D lines along the Z-axis as patients differ in height and size. I am not sure how to approach this problem of z-axis scaling while maintaining the relationship of the x and y axes with regard to z.

```py
print(spine_landmark_data_x.head(1).T)
print(spine_landmark_data_y.head(1).T)
print(spine_landmark_data_z.head(1).T)
```

[Output of dataframes from above code (X,Y,Z coordinates in 3 separate dataframes)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifnB3.png)

```py
test_x = spine_landmark_data_x.copy()
test_y = spine_landmark_data_y.copy()
test_z = spine_landmark_data_z.copy()

# Scale each patient z-axis from 0 to 1
for row in range(spine_landmark_data.shape[0]):
    test_z.iloc[row] = spine_landmark_data_z.iloc[row] - spine_landmark_data_z.iloc[row].min()
    test_z.iloc[row] = test_z.iloc[row] / test_z.iloc[row].max()
    
    test_y.iloc[row] = spine_landmark_data_y.iloc[row] - spine_landmark_data_y.iloc[row].min()
    test_y.iloc[row] = test_y.iloc[row] / test_y.iloc[row].max()
    
    test_x.iloc[row] = spine_landmark_data_x.iloc[row] - spine_landmark_data_x.iloc[row].min()
    test_x.iloc[row] = test_x.iloc[row] / test_x.iloc[row].max()
```

[Plots that the above code produces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7QUp.png)

Comment: Out of curiosity, you don't want to use numpy at this stage ?

Comment: @PlainRavioli use numpy to deal with these as arrays as compared to pandas dataframes? the df structure makes it easier for me to keep track of things and I do not necessarily see a large benefit in using numpy

Comment: yes :) (comments are 15c min sorry random text)

Comment: no worries. if there is benefit for using numpy over pandas that you can see, please let me know! ty

Comment: For everything numerical-only and once the data is cleaned, I tend to use numpy only as it lots of computational features and is overall very adapted for array processing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would the following work?

```py
test_x = spine_landmark_data_x.copy()
test_y = spine_landmark_data_y.copy()
test_z = spine_landmark_data_z.copy()

# Scale each patient z-axis from 0 to 1
for row in range(spine_landmark_data.shape[0]):
    # scaling factor = 1.0 / (patient's z data range)
    scaling_factor = 1.0 / (spine_landmark_data_z.iloc[row].max() - spine_landmark_data_z.iloc[row].min())
    test_z.iloc[row] = (spine_landmark_data_z.iloc[row] - spine_landmark_data_z.iloc[row].min()) * scaling_factor
    test_y.iloc[row] = (spine_landmark_data_y.iloc[row] - spine_landmark_data_y.iloc[row].min()) * scaling_factor
    test_x.iloc[row] = (spine_landmark_data_x.iloc[row] - spine_landmark_data_x.iloc[row].min()) * scaling_factor
```

It differs only slightly from your existing code in that it scales all axes by the same factor which was used to normalize the z range to [0, 1].